# Jersey JAX-RS - matching regular expression

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following resources:

**rounds resource**

```
@Path("/rounds")
public class RoundResource {
  RoundService roundService = new RoundService();

    @Path("{roundUri}/matches")
    public MatchResource getMatchResource() {
        return new MatchResource();
    }
}
```

**teams resource**

```
@Path("/teams")
public class TeamResource {
    TeamService teamService = new TeamService();

    @Path("/{teamUri}/matches")
    public MatchResource getMatchResource() {
        return new MatchResource();
    }
}
```

**matches resource**

```
@Path("/matches")
public class MatchResource {
    private MatchService matchService = new MatchService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Match> getTeamMatches(@PathParam("teamUri") String teamUri) {
        return matchService.getTeamMatches(teamUri);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Match> getRoundMatches(@PathParam("roundUri") String roundUri) {
        return matchService.getRoundMatches(roundUri);
    }
}
```

Where

```
/rounds/{roundUri}/matches
```

gets the matches of a round

```
/teams/{teamUri}/matches
```

gets the matches of a team

I got the matching regular expression error because the path in **matches** resource is **/matches** and both paths end with it. How to solve it?

Comment: I don't see any thing related to regular expression here change the question

Comment: Error obtained: A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public java.util.List spl.ws.euro2016.resource.MatchResource.getTeamMatches(java.lang.String) and public java.util.List spl.ws.euro2016.resource.MatchResource.getRoundMatches(java.lang.String) at **matching regular expression /matches.**

Comment: edited my answer take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added @Path("**OPTION**") annotation to the match resource methods to specify if I want the matches by round or by team:

**rounds resource**

```
@Path("/rounds")
public class RoundResource {
  RoundService roundService = new RoundService();

    @Path("{roundUri}/matches")
    public MatchResource getMatchResource() {
        return new MatchResource();
    }
}
```

**teams resource**

```
@Path("/teams")
public class TeamResource {
    TeamService teamService = new TeamService();

    @Path("/{teamUri}/matches")
    public MatchResource getMatchResource() {
        return new MatchResource();
    }
}
```

**matches resource**

```
@Path("/matches")
public class MatchResource {
    private MatchService matchService = new MatchService();

    @GET
    @Path("/byteam")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Match> getTeamMatches(@PathParam("teamUri") String teamUri) {
        return matchService.getTeamMatches(teamUri);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/byround")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Match> getRoundMatches(@PathParam("roundUri") String roundUri) {
        return matchService.getRoundMatches(roundUri);
    }
}
```

Now I have:

```
/rounds/{roundUri}/matches/byround
```

gets the matches of a round

```
/teams/{teamUri}/matches/byteam
```

gets the matches of a team

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your matches resource . The two methods map to same url i,e

/matches So if you are not giving any @Path annotation to the methods then only one method should be there to avoid collision or give @Path annotation to either one of them or to both of them . it will work

I don't see why you have mentioned regular expression in your question . When the question you are asking is nothing related to regular expression .

Anyway to give pattern for path parameters you can add code like this

```
@Path("method1/{parameter1: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*}") // this regular  expression is for alphanumeric
```

you should have both @Path annotation on method  and @PathParam annotation on argument to work properly

you should code like this in your matches resource

```
@Path("{teamUri}")
```

and

```
@Path("/roundUri/{roundUri}")
```

on your methods to work

this will work for urls like `/matches/xxxdf` and `/matches/roundUri/xalfo`

change your code like this it will work

```
@Path("/matches")
public class MatchResource {
private MatchService matchService = new MatchService();

@GET
@Path("{teamUri}")
 //or  @Path("{teamUri:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*}") if you want to use regular expressions
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Match> getTeamMatches(@PathParam("teamUri") String teamUri) {
    return matchService.getTeamMatches(teamUri);
}

@GET
@Path("roundUri/{roudUri}")
  //or  @Path("{roundUri:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*}") if you want to use regular expressions
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Match> getRoundMatches(@PathParam("roundUri") String roundUri) {
    return matchService.getRoundMatches(roundUri);
}
}
```

**The point here is your url for resources should not clash**

Comment: Dear I want to maintain these and only these URIs: **/rounds/{roundUri}/matches**
gets the matches of a round

**/teams/{teamUri}/matches** 
gets the matches of a team

Comment: then why are you creating  /matches resource please refer https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

Comment: because I have another method to get a specific match, where I have: **/matches/21** for example, and don't want it to be **/rounds/{roundUri}/matches/21**

Comment: if your teamUri and roundUri has different patterns then you can use the commented annotation i used in code above . just uncomment it and use required regex . and comment the @Path annotation that is not commented .  or else you have to use different paths in matches resource if they have same pattern . if you want same path and patterns of both teamUri and roundUri is same then i can't help you